# XML template 500 error with one category group

Tags: template-scripting, xml, error-500

I"m setting up an xml template on an old site to use for importing to a new site via datagrab. Everything is working fine except when I try to output categories from one specific category group. When I do that the page gives a 500 error.

Here is the relevant part of my template

```
<root>
{exp:channel:entries channel="trips" paginate="bottom" status="Open|Closed" limit="500" dynamic="off"}
    <entry>

        <categories>

        {!-- // causes 500 error on page load not sure why
            <cat_activities>
                {categories show_group="6" backspace="1"}
                    <![CDATA[{category_name}]]>,
                {/categories}
            </cat_activities>
        --}


            <cat_difficulty-class>
                {categories show_group="7" backspace="1"}
                    <![CDATA[{category_name}]]>,
                {/categories}
            </cat_difficulty-class>

        </categories>

    </entry>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</root>
```

I've taken the same code and put it into a test html template and there are no errors and it outputs the categories as expected. See below:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="trips" paginate="bottom" status="Open|Closed" limit="500" dynamic="off"}

            <cat_activities>
                {categories show_group="6" backspace="1"}
                    {category_name},<br>
                {/categories}
            </cat_activities>

            <cat_difficulty-class>
                {categories show_group="7" backspace="1"}
                    {category_name},<br>
                {/categories}
            </cat_difficulty-class>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any idea on why the xml template is getting a 500 error? As soon as I comment out the one category group the xml template loads correctly.

***********UPDATE***************

I also checked that the categories in this category group don't have any special characters or anything that would obviously affect output in either the title or url_title. Have attached screenshot of categories.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can’t see any problem off hand, but I’d try some of this:

- According to [the docs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/channel/channel_entries.html#categories-tag-pair-parameters), the backspace parameter counts 
   as four characters, so change the backspace value to 4.
- Removing the `<br>`
- Removing the backspace parameter
- Ensure that category group is indeed assigned to the ‘trips’ channel
- Try putting group 6 after group 7 and see if the same thing happens

Comment: Putting group 6 after group 7 resolved this. Thank you.